# Remove repeating data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 columns of data `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.
Some data are repeating such as row 1: `P2  XX  P6  XX` is repeating in row 5: `P6  XX  P2  XX`. Can anyone help me to remove the repeating units from Pandas dataframe?

```
A   B   C   D
P2  XX  P6  XX
P3  XX  P5  XX
P5  XX  P8  XX
P5  XX  P3  XX
P6  XX  P2  XX
P8  XX  P5  XX
P1  LU  P2  LU
P2  LU  P1  LU
P3  LU  P9  LU
P3  LU  P6  LU
P6  LU  P3  LU
P9  LU  P3  LU
```

Output:

```
A  B  C  D 
P2 XX P6 XX 
P3 XX P5 XX 
P5 XX P8 XX 
P1 LU P2 LU 
P3 LU P9 LU 
P3 LU P6 LU
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) on axis=1 sort sort values in rows, then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates) on the sorted frame. Lastly, use the index to filter `df`:

```
import numpy as np


idx = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.sort(df.values, axis=1), columns=df.columns
    ).drop_duplicates().index
)

df = df.loc[idx]
```

Or without a second variable:

```
df = df.loc[
    pd.DataFrame(
        np.sort(df.values, axis=1), columns=df.columns
    ).drop_duplicates().index
]
```

`df`:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  P2  XX  P6  XX
1  P3  XX  P5  XX
2  P5  XX  P8  XX
6  P1  LU  P2  LU
8  P3  LU  P9  LU
9  P3  LU  P6  LU
```

Comment: And if considering my data set has
Input:
A    B    C    D

P1   XX   P1   LU

P1   XX   P9   LU

P1   XX   P3   LU

P10  XX   P10  LU

P2   XX   P8   LU

P4   XX   P1   LU

P6   XX   P8   LU

P7   XX   P10  LU

P9   XX   P3   LU

P1   LU   P4   XX

P1   LU   P1   XX

P10  LU   P7   XX

P10  LU   P10  XX

P3   LU   P1   XX

P3   LU   P9   XX

P8   LU   P2   XX

P8   LU   P6   XX

P9   LU   P1   XX

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's okay to swap columns `A` and `C`, you can use `np.minimum` and `np.maximum` to swap the two columns and then drop duplicates:

```
import numpy as np
df.A, df.C = np.minimum(df.A, df.C), np.maximum(df.A, df.C)

df.drop_duplicates()
    A   B   C   D
0  P2  XX  P6  XX
1  P3  XX  P5  XX
2  P5  XX  P8  XX
6  P1  LU  P2  LU
8  P3  LU  P9  LU
9  P3  LU  P6  LU
```